# How can I move line up in Vim text editor?

Tags: vim

I have two strings in some file, e.g.:

```
string1
string2
```

And I want to get this:

```
string1string2
```

How can I do this most efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Shift-j</kbd> (`J`) for "join" will move the line under the cursor up to the previous line. Note that this also inserts a space at the end of the line. If you type <kbd>g Shift-j</kbd>, no space will be appended when joining.

You can join multiple lines at once by highlighting them. For example, <kbd>gg Shift-v Shift-g Shift-j</kbd> `ggVGJ` will join all lines in the file.

You can refer to `:help join` in vim for more information.